# how to select haproxy backends (same server using different port) based on incoming request?

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to route the traffic based on the incoming request and the backend server I'm using is same but on different ports. However, all the traffic is going to the same backend pserver irrespective of the incoming request. Can someone help me?

```
frontend defhttps-in

   acl host_portal hdr(host) -i server1:80  
   acl host_mobility hdr(host) -i server1:81  
   acl host_mobility path_beg /HHServlet  
   acl host_mobility path_beg /ota  
   acl host_mobility path_beg /TransportServlet  
   use_backend pservers if host_portal  
   use_backend mobileservers if host_mobility  
   default_backend pservers    


backend pservers  
    balance roundrobin  
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix nocache  
    cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache  
    option httpchk get /StatusServlet  
    http-check expect ! string red  
    server portal1 server1:80  cookie P1 check  

backend mobileservers  
    balance roundrobin  
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix nocache  
    cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache  
    option httpchk get /StatusServlet  
    http-check expect ! string red  
    server mobility1 server1:81 cookie M1 check
```

Answer (score 1):

See my config file below, and modify yours accordingly.

I suggest that you watch these videos and read these resources to help better understand HAProxy.

Videos:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fgi2H737Y4
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77wXzh_Kjv0

HAProxy Blogs:

- https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-acls/
- https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/10-0/traffic-management/lb-layer7/acls/

Config file:

```
##############################

global
      log         127.0.0.1 syslog
      maxconn     1000
      user        haproxy
      group       haproxy
      daemon


    defaults
      log  global
      mode  http
      option  httplog
      option  dontlognull
      option  http-server-close
      option  forwardfor except 127.0.0.0/8
      option  redispatch
      option  contstats
      retries  3
      timeout  http-request 10s
      timeout  queue 1m
      timeout  connect 10s
      timeout  client 1m
      timeout  server 1m
      timeout  check 10s
      errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
      errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
      errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
      errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
      errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
      errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
      errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http


    ###########################################
    #
    # HAProxy Stats page
    #
    ###########################################

    listen stats
      bind *:9090
      mode  http
      maxconn  10
      stats  enable
      stats  hide-version
      stats  realm Haproxy\ Statistics
      stats  uri /
      stats  auth -----:-----



    ###########################################
    #
    # Front end for all
    #
    ###########################################

    frontend ALL
      bind   *:80
      mode   http

      # Define path for lets encrypt
      acl is_letsencrypt path_beg -i /.well-known/acme-challenge/
      use_backend letsencrypt if is_letsencrypt

      # Define hosts
      acl host_horizon hdr(host) -i horizon.eduarmor.com
      acl host_eduarmor hdr(host) -i www.eduarmor.com
      acl host_nextcloud hdr(host) -i nextcloud.eduarmor.com
      acl host_git hdr(host) -i git.eduarmor.com
      acl host_minecraft hdr(host) -i mine.eduarmor.com
      acl host_sugar hdr(host) -i sugar.eduarmor.com
      acl host_maas hdr(host) -i maas.eduarmor.com
      acl host_rocketchat hdr(host) -i rocketchat.eduarmor.com
      acl host_hive hdr(host) -i hive.eduarmor.com
      acl host_portainer hdr(host) -i portainer.eduarmor.com

      # Direct hosts to backend
      use_backend horizon if host_horizon
      use_backend eduarmor if host_eduarmor
      use_backend nextcloud if host_nextcloud
      use_backend git if host_git
      use_backend minecraft if host_minecraft
      use_backend sugar if host_sugar
      use_backend maas if host_maas
      use_backend rocketchat if host_rocketchat
      use_backend hive if host_hive
      use_backend portainer if host_portainer

    ###########################################
    #
    # Back end letsencrypt
    #
    ###########################################

    backend letsencrypt
      server letsencrypt 127.0.0.1:8888

    ###########################################
    #
    # Back end for Horizon
    #
    ###########################################

    backend horizon
      balance         roundrobin
      # option          httpchk GET /check
      option          httpchk GET /
      # http-check      expect rstring ^UP$
      default-server  inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
      server          server1 10.0.0.30:80 check
      #     server          server2 0.0.0.0:80 check
    ###########################################
    #
    # Back end for EduArmor
    #
    ###########################################
    backend eduarmor
      balance         roundrobin
      # option          httpchk GET /check
      option          httpchk GET /
      # http-check      expect rstring ^UP$
      default-server  inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
      server          server1 10.0.0.59:80 check
      #     server server2 0.0.0.0:80 check

    ##########################################
    #
    # Back end for Nextcloud
    #
    ##########################################
    backend nextcloud
      balance         roundrobin
      # option         httpchk GET /check
      option          httpchk GET /
      # http-check     expect rstring ^UP$
      default-server  inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
      server          server1 10.0.0.101:80 check


    ##########################################
    #
    # Back end, Gitlab
    #
    ##########################################
    backend git
     balance        roundrobin
     # option        httpchk GET /check
     option         httpchk GET /
     # http-check    expect rstring ^UP$
     default-server inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
     server         server1 10.0.0.101:800 check
     server         server2 10.0.0.102:800 check



    ##########################################
    #
    # Back end, Minecraft
    #
    ##########################################
    backend minecraft
     balance        roundrobin
     # option        httpchk GET /check
     option         httpchk GET /
     # http-check    expect rstring ^UP$
     default-server inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
     server         server1 10.0.0.101:25565 check
```